# How to watch for ng-model created with ng-bind-html with "controller as" syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In a [previous topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24560540/how-to-watch-for-ng-model-created-with-ng-bind-html/32392741?noredirect=1#comment52656236_32392741) a solution was given to use ng-model inside of generated code. The solution was to implement a custom directive:

```
app.directive('compile',function($compile, $timeout){
    return{
        restrict:'A',
        link: function(scope,elem,attrs){
            $timeout(function(){                
                $compile(elem.contents())(scope);    
            });
        }        
    };
});
```

And to use it like an attribute:

```
   <div compile class="options" ng-bind-html="item.options"></div>
```

I'm trying to obtain the same result using the "controller as" syntax but I couldn't find a way to do it. In my controller I don't want to use $scope as in Angular 2.0 there won't be any.

Comment: can you explain what you mean: _I'm trying to obtain the same result using the "controller as" syntax_?